# how can I install pygame on both python 2 and 3 on the same computer?

Tags: python, pygame

How can I install pygame on both python 2 and 3 on the same computer?
Its working with python 2 but i cant install it on python 3.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, show your work. Explain your problem and tell us what you expect to happen versus what's really happening. That way we can help you.

Comment: I figured out. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). It will allow each project to have its own version of python and keeps all its python packages stored next to the project, rather than globally on the system.

- `cd` into your project directory
- Install a version of python 2 on your system
- `$ virtualenv p2env --python=2.7`
- Install a version of python 3 on your system
- `$ virtualenv p3env --python=3.5`

You can how "activate" either of those environments.

```
$ ./p2env/bin/activate
```

You'll see your command prompt gets prefixed with the name of the environment. You're now running under that version of python. Additionally, any packages you `pip install` will be installed locally for that specific environment.

To deactivate the environment type the following.

```
$ deactivate
```

You should notice the environment name is removed from the command prompt. You're now able to switch to a new environment if you wish.

Make sure you add the environment directories virtualenv created to your `.gitignore` file.

```
/p2env
/p3env
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Most linux distributions do so:

```
~$ python
python      python2     python2.7   python3     python3.4   python3.4m  python3m
~$ python
```

Debian symlinks `python` to `python2.7` so you need to run python3 explicitly. On all other systems you can also have multiple versions in parallel in the same fashion.

Also there is a tool `virtualenv` which might help you in creating and manageing completely isolated python environments. (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Please format your code correctly using the built in editor tools. I fixed them for you this time.